# Dragon NaturallySpeaking: Page Up multiple pages

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

Using Dragon NaturallySpeaking (Dragon dictation), is it possible to move up/down multiple pages at a time?  If I'm in an Excel  spreadsheet, it could take a very long time to move up a thousand rows otherwise.

I know I can say "up *X* lines" (though this is unreliable for large numbers) or "page up" *X* times,  but it doesn't look as though I can say "up *X* pages" or anything else of which I can think.

*(Version 11)*

Comment: What's wrong with "Page Up X times"? Doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: That just prints the text "page up six times."  Are you experiencing different behavior? What version do you own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Premium

If you use Dragon NaturallySpeaking Premium, you can say:

- "press Page Up" - presses <kbd>PgUp</kbd> once.
- Excel only: "Row twenty", "Column Delta", asf. (It's built in.) The focus jumps right there.
- Excel only: Use some of the scrolling commands. Read the Dragon Help file and search for Excel. There is a number of articles covering various commands for Excel.
- Paid alternative: buy a utility such as KnowBrainer that includes tons of these commands. (Not affiliated.)
- Free alternative for any program: Create an AutoHotkey script, place it on your desktop and open it with the "*Open* " command.

AutoHotkey code for PgUp 5 times:

```
Send {PgUp 5}
Exit
```

#### Pro, Legal and Medical

All of the above works, too.

Plus: you can create your custom commands fairly easily. You can script whatever you like with a VBA dialect that is not all that hard to learn. Commands like *Page Up Five, Jump Up Ten* - or whatever else may please you - are at your disposal. You can improve your productivity by creating your own macros this way.

#### Bottom line

I think that you should be covered by what is in the Help file. There's tons of info in there. To open it, just say "help me". (This is best anyway, because it covers the version you own. I haven't used 11 for some time. I'm on 12 now. There should not be differences, but you never know.)

Comment: Thanks. ...But, alas, I'm using LibreOffice, not Excel. (My machine runs Linux.) And I don't have Pro, so I guess I can't script my own commands. ...But it's a great answer.

Comment: You can look at natlink/vocola/unimacro projects to add functionality to dragon naturally speaking, haven't tried it yet though, but it should be able to do what you want